# How do I determine if the Oracle Instant client or the full client is installed?

Tags: oracle11g

I have a version of Oracle client installed .. tnsping says its version 11.2.0.1.0. 
What I want to know is if its the Instant client or the full client. There must be a
simple way to determine this but I'm not seeing it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you know how to check the oracle client version?

Comment: dlopen libclntsh.so + call OCIVersion.

Comment: see thats strange about the tnsPing not being present in the instant client because I just installed the IC (12c) on Server 2012 and tnsping was there ..

Comment: @carlodurso - I just typed tnsping in the windows command prompt